# Creating schedules based on student and professor times of availability

Tags: php, time, scheduling

We have X number of students, every student is available from studentStartTime till studentEndTime. We have 1 professor, professor work hours are profesorStartTime till professorEndTime. Every class lasts for N minutes.

Function needs to place all given students within profesorStartTime-profesorEndTime, while not breaking student availability times (intervals). If there is no solution function should return false.

Kinda need a lot of help with this problem. Don’t care about programming language just would like to see solution.

Comment: Post your solution first and describe your issues with it, this is no 'sendmetehcodez' place.

Comment: I don't even think you have enough requirements for this to make sense. Shouldn't there be some class information?  Max number of students that can see the professor at once? etc

Comment: One student per professor at time, what do you mean when you say class information ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *curriculum course* example in [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner), which is about scheduling courses (lessons) into timeslots based on subscribed students and teacher availability.

The code is open source and [available on github](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-planner/tree/master/drools-planner-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/planner/examples/curriculumcourse).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look thorough it